# Postgresql Timestamp Min Max Incorrect/ How to handle outliers

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-timestamp

this is my first post, so pls be patient with me. I'm fairly new at sql, but i think i have a few basics down.

I'm trying to calculate how much time each person is on site. There are serveral timestamp so i've been using the following code

```
MIN (to_char(c.capture_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) AS "start day",              
MAX(to_char(c.capture_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) AS "end of day",
```

And i get the following output

```
User        Project     Start Day       End Day     
person A    project 1   6/10/20 15:10   6/10/20 20:43       
person A    project 2   6/11/20 12:10   6/11/20 16:10       
person B    project 8   6/11/20 11:10   6/11/20 18:23
```

I then download the data to csv file and calculate the duration by doing (end-start)*24

This code works for ~85% of the users/projects

The problem I start running in to is when there are outlier cases or timestap goes in to the next day

Problem 1 - outliers (raw data)

```
User        Project     Capture End time        
person A    Project 1   6/10/20 15:10       
person A    Project 1   6/10/20 15:20       
person A    Project 1   6/10/20 15:40       
person A    Project 1   6/10/20 16:05       
person A    Project 1   6/10/20 20:43
```

In this example the last time stamp is off, you can tell that by the large time gap. I need to somehow ignore extreme outliers

Problem 2 - timestamp goes into next day (raw data)

```
User        Project     Capture End Time
person B    Project 2   6/15/20 23:12
person B    Project 2   6/15/20 23:45
person B    Project 2   6/16/20 0:15
person B    Project 2   6/16/20 0:30
person B    Project 2   6/16/20 20:05
person B    Project 2   6/16/20 20:30
```

I get the following results(output):

```
User        Project     Start Day       End Day
person B    Project 2   6/15/20 23:12   6/15/20 23:45
person B    Project 2   6/16/20 0:15    6/16/20 20:30
```

Instead of (desired results):

```
User        Project     Start Day       End Day
person B    Project 2   6/15/20 23:12   6/16/20 0:30
person B    Project 2   6/16/20 20:05   6/16/20 20:30
```

I'm not sure how to approach this problem, so i'd appreciate any guidance

Comment: Show the data as it appears in the table in the database.  And then, why aren't you just doing the entire calculation in the database?  And if your goal is to calculate duration, why doesn't any of the sample data have a duration column?

Comment: "...the last time stamp is off, you can tell that by the large time gap" -- What is a "large time gap"? Please specify how long of a time needs to be considered a long time gap.

Comment: This is a "Gaps & Islands" problem. There are plenty of canned solutions for it.

Comment: You should do the min/max() _before_ converting the timestamp to a string: `to_char(min(capture_time), '...')`

Comment: @GordonLinoff I didn't show the data as it appears in the database b/c this is protected company data & i'm using 7 different tables to pull all the information together. I'm not calculating duration b/c I'm still figuring out how to do that (I'm not a programmer, i picked this up last week)

Comment: @TheImpaler okay, i will look up "gap & island" problems

Answer (score 0):

This is a "Gaps & Islands" problem with the twist that there can be a delay to consider when to "close a day". I decided to use a 2-hour minimum gap between days. You can change this to a longer or shorter gap to suit your needs.

The following query produces the result you are asking:

```
select usr, project,
  min(captured) as start_day,
  max(captured) as end_day
from (
  select *,
    sum(new_group) over(partition by usr, project order by captured) as day
  from (
    select *,
      case when captured > 
        max(captured) over(partition by usr, project order by captured
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) + interval '2 hour'
        then 1 else 0
      end as new_group
    from t
  ) x
) y
group by usr, project, day
```

Result:

```
usr        project     start_day                  end_day                   
--------- ----------- -------------------------- -------------------------- 
Person B   project 2   2020-06-15T23:12:00.000Z   2020-06-16T00:30:00.000Z  
Person B   project 2   2020-06-16T20:05:00.000Z   2020-06-16T20:30:00.000Z
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tk3QPWefJT6DC6BQF5PhRm/0).